# fit row height of a uitableview to his content

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, height, row

Hi I'm trying to fit my row height of my table view to his content, but the height doesn't take the good size:

[image]

For the cells I use a Cocoa Touch class subclass of UITableViewCell:

[image]

I tried this 2 lines:

```
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 160.0

    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

But it doesn't work.

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 38.0/255.0, green: 51.0/255.0, blue: 85.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Gotham", size: 13)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor()]
    self.title = "ACTUALITÉS"

    let nib = UINib(nibName: "actuVwCell", bundle: nil)
    tableView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")


    self.beginParsing()

    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 160.0

    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

EDIT

[image]

ActualitesViewController:

```
import UIKit

@objc
protocol ActualitesViewControllerDelegate {
    optional func toggleLeftPanel()
    optional func collapseSidePanels()
}

class ActualitesViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, NSXMLParserDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    var parser = NSXMLParser()
    var posts = NSMutableArray()
    var elements = NSMutableDictionary()
    var element = NSString()
    var title1 = NSMutableString()
    var date = NSMutableString()
    var dscrptn = NSMutableString()

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 38.0/255.0, green: 51.0/255.0, blue: 85.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Gotham", size: 13)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor()]
        self.title = "ACTUALITÉS"

        let nib = UINib(nibName: "actuVwCell", bundle: nil)
        tableView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")


        self.beginParsing()

        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 160.0
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func beginParsing()
    {
        posts = []
        parser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL:(NSURL(string:"http:...rss.html"))!)!
        parser.delegate = self
        parser.parse()

        tableView!.reloadData()
    }

    //XMLParser Methods

    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String])
    {
        element = elementName
        if (elementName as NSString).isEqualToString("item")
        {
            elements = NSMutableDictionary()
            elements = [:]
            title1 = NSMutableString()
            title1 = ""
            date = NSMutableString()
            date = ""
            dscrptn = NSMutableString()
            dscrptn = ""
        }
    }

    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?)
    {
        if (elementName as NSString).isEqualToString("item") {
            if !title1.isEqual(nil) {
                elements.setObject(title1, forKey: "title")
            }
            if !date.isEqual(nil) {
                elements.setObject(date, forKey: "date")
            }
            if !dscrptn.isEqual(nil) {
                elements.setObject(dscrptn, forKey: "dscrptn")
            }

            posts.addObject(elements)
        }
    }

    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String)
    {
        if element.isEqualToString("title") {
            title1.appendString(string)
        } else if element.isEqualToString("pubDate") {
            date.appendString(string)
        } else if element.isEqualToString("description") {
            dscrptn.appendString(string)
        }
    }

    //Tableview Methods

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return posts.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell:ActuTblCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! ActuTblCell

        /*
        if(cell.isEqual(NSNull)) {
            cell = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("cell", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as! ActuTblCell;
        }
        */

        cell.titleActuCell.numberOfLines = 0
        cell.titleActuCell.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
        cell.titleActuCell.sizeToFit()

        cell.dateActuCell.numberOfLines = 0
        cell.dateActuCell.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
        cell.dateActuCell.sizeToFit()

        cell.descriptionActuCell.numberOfLines = 0
        cell.descriptionActuCell.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
        cell.descriptionActuCell.sizeToFit()


        cell.titleActuCell.text = posts.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("title") as! NSString as String

        cell.dateActuCell.text = posts.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("date") as! NSString as String


        cell.descriptionActuCell.text = posts.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("dscrptn") as! NSString as String

        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method?

Comment: @DejanSkledar no but I want to size from the content and don't put a height value, because sometimes I have 4 or 6 lines in the description from the subclass of UITableViewCell

Comment: yes.. you can still set the height for each row in that method, but ofcourse autolayout is better though..

Comment: @DejanSkledar you mean that I can try to use: `heightForRowAtIndexPath =  UITableViewAutomaticDimension` ?

Comment: You can help with this example: https://github.com/smileyborg/TableViewCellWithAutoLayoutiOS8

Answer (score 2):

You should use AutoLayout and you need to make sure that you have all vertical constraints added (from top to bottom).
I had same problem when I tried use:

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

The solution was remove that line and put it to `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Comment: I have tried and succeeded with this approach. but need to take care of table view cell constraints.

Comment: If you don't want to use constraints you have to calculate cell height in code in heightForRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: That's hard to configure vertical constraints

Comment: I have 3 Label and I want to have one under the other, the first have to get a constraint on the top, and the last on the bottom I think, but I can't put a Label under an another...

Comment: That's very easy to do. You are using auto layout anyway so you should go for the solution in my answer. Read any tutorial about auto layout that's the basic stuff you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I'm gonna see that, I just put all of my code, but I think they're nothing false here

Comment: @greg I just tried with one Label, I added constraints on top left right bottom to 0, but thats doesn't work too

Comment: I have a problem, my app take this line: `tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 160.0` and if I delete this line, only 2 lines of the description is displayed

Comment: Try remove this line and add this method:

Comment: Try remove this line and add this method:func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 160.0
    }

Comment: It's look working, but it take the highest row and it put his height to the other, but I want to have different heights

Comment: I have only two methods implemented heightForRowAtIndexPath with UITableViewAutomaticDimension and estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath. There are constraint seated in IB and I also set numberOfLines = 0 and lineBreakMode on the labels in code and all works fine. Maybe your constraints are wrong.

Comment: I can't find my problem, everything looks correct, can I show you my constraints ?

Comment: Use a cacao touch class like a subview of UITableViewCell is correct ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> CGFloat {
  return 160
}
```